# PHP: try/catch fail

Tags: php, mysql, exception, laravel-3

I'm running WAMSERVER 2.4 (32-bit) with PHP 5.4.16, this is a Laravel 3 project.

In a `try` block, which I'm expecting to fail, I am submitting a duplicate row for insertion against a uniqueness constraint.
Instead of handling the exception in the `catch`, it's throwing an *"Unhandled Exception"* error from the `try` block and failing.

```
    // This throws an error if the relationship already exists.
    // If that happens, just pass it to the logger and move on.
    try {
        $entity->$pivotMethod()->attach( $rowData->get_key(), $ext );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $err = $e->getMessage()."\n";
        error_log($err);
    }
```

Here's the error it throws:
Unhandled Exception

Message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '695d7f0b-53b8-11e3-93fc-c12677e410a5-0-0-14-' for key 'unique'
>
> SQL: INSERT INTO `person_contact` (`person_uuid`,`phone_id`) VALUES (?, ?)
>   Bindings: array( 0 => '695d7f0b-53b8-11e3-93fc-c12677e410a5', 1 => 14)
>
> Location: C:\path\to\laravel\3_2_13\database\connection.php on line 263

Comment: If not exception is thrown it will never reach the catch block

Comment: +1 Yes it is! You must throw exceptions

Comment: Is your block above inside a class within a namespace?

Comment: try `\Exception` instead of `Exception`

Comment: That did it (namespacing)! Thanks @Machavity and #DanFromGermany .. you guys are so smart :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comment here's your problem

```
namespace Something;

class myClass {

    function method() {
          try {
        $entity->$pivotMethod()->attach( $rowData->get_key(), $ext );
       } catch (Exception $e) {
        $err = $e->getMessage()."\n";
        error_log($err);
       }
    }
}
```

In this case you're typehinting that you're catching an exception but you don't specify a scope so PHP is assuming you're catching `\Something\Exception`

The fix is pretty simple. Adding a `\` tells PHP to catch anything that is, or extends, the base `Exception` class

```
catch (\Exception $e)
```

Comment: **+1** I hope you didn't just get this answer from the comments, *DanFromGermany* found it out first :)

Comment: I knew this solution because I had the same problem few months ago, but his guess came in first *Is your block above inside a class within a namespace?* Your all welcome

Comment: No, that's why I asked if it was in a namespace. I've run across this type of problem before. When you typehint like that, PHP gets VERY specific. Unless you know you're going to be catching a specific type of exception, it's almost always best to use `\Exception`